# what form of authentication should i implement in my winform c# application to gain access to folders in a SharePoint site?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, forms-authentication, basic-authentication, restful-authentication

i'm currently creating a winform application using c# and i'm wondering how do i go about implementing an authentication function in my application so that user will be able to gain access to the SharePoint site with the right credentials (username and password). is there any way other than using the web services of SharePoint? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

best way i have found is to use SharePoint Client Object Model. Links below. hope this helps!
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/399156/SharePoint-Client-Object-Model-Introduction